# spring scanning same type bean with different names returning ambiguous exception after upgrading to spring-boot 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I recently upgraded my application to spring-boot 3.2 from spring-boot 3.0.x. After upgrading we are getting several bean ambiguous exceptions, This was working fine before,

Ex) The Application is consuming several client libraries and each client library is creating RestTemplate using the below code,

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AutoConfiguration
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.partner.tracker.client"})
public class TrackerClientConfiguration {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private RestTemplateCustomizer restTemplateCustomizer;
    
    @Bean(name = "trackerRestTemplate")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "trackerRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate trackerRestTemplate() {
        return createTrackerRestTemplate();
    }

    public RestTemplate createTrackerRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .requestFactory(this::customHttpRequestFactory)
                .interceptors(
                        getDefaultHeadersInterceptor(),
                        getTraceIdInterceptor()
                )
                .messageConverters(getMessageConverters());
        if (Objects.nonNull(restTemplateCustomizer)) {
            restTemplateBuilder = restTemplateBuilder.additionalCustomizers(restTemplateCustomizer);
        }
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

We are using the same code for other 5-libraries RestTemplate creation.

This was working fine till we upgraded to spring-boot 3.2 but we got the below exception after upgrading to 3.2

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.tracker.client.TrackerApiClient required a single bean, but 6 were found:

- ulfRestTemplate: defined in file <file location>
- trackerRestTemplate: defined in file <file location>
- homeRestTemplate: defined by method
- pluginRestTemplate: defined by method
- partnerRestTemplate: defined by method
- goRestTemplate: defined by method

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed.
```

So we are using @Qualifier annotation temporarily to fix this issue but I don't want to do that since it breaks unit testing also I use Lombok for constructor injection now I should go with manual constructor with @Qualifier annotation.

so this bug was recently introduced by the spring team or is this how spring always works for the same type of bean? If this is the usual behaviour then I wonder how it works in the past.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use @Primary on your trackerRestTemplate instead of @Qualifier?

Comment: Add `-parameter` to your compiler. Previous versions generated a warning and did a fallback, this fallback has been removed (in accordance with the error). If you don't compile with `-parameters` the constructor argument has some generated name instead of an actual name that would match the bean name. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38607 as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is due Spring 6.1 having removed the `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` which acted like a fallback when the code was not compiled with `-parameters`. When this fallback was used a warning was generated with a message that this was deprecated and will be removed in future versions. That future is now.

To fix add `-parameters` to your compiler options to retain the parameter names, instead of some generated name.

See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38607) as well, while closed holds some references to related issues with more information. In addition this change is also mentioned in [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes#parameter-name-discovery).